# Какие есть эффективные способы для надежность активации программы? c#

Tags: c#, защита, активация

*Доброго времени вам*! Возможно такие вопросы были.
Делал раньше активацию программы, через хостинг. Т.е записывал сгенерированный ключ и выдавал пользователю.

Теперь у меня сайт, там человек после покупки программы, скачивает её, программа выдает ключ, после этого он должен этот ключ активировать на сайте для записи в базу данных.

На сколько такой метод надежный? Есть ли другие способы активации программы? Потому что мне кажется это ерунда и бред полнейший, так как человек спокойно может взломать программу и убрать проверку, или отключится от базы данных.

Я вот смотрел, заинтересовался что есть какой то WFC, но не совсем понял для чего он. Вроде бы какой то `что-ли` сервер, он может принимать данные и возвращать программе. Но в чем разница между ним и базой данных?

Или все таки как то прятать программу а активация должна быть отдельно.
Еще пугает то, что после того как взломащик взломает программу, сможет узнать данные от базы данных, ну и вы понимаете что там крантык всему.

Просто не понимаю логику. Не могли бы вы мне разъяснить ответы на мои вопросы. Рассказать или показать дополнительные источники информации о защиты программы.
Как делается надежная активация и защита программы? Вроде бы эти два вопроса связаны по смыслу, ну мне не хватает просто записать активированный ключ в базу данных и проверку на активацию ключа. **Как спрятать программу?** **Как спрятать проверку активации?** **Как спрятать данные от бд?** **Как может быть запутать код программы?** **Возможно сделать как то сервер, который будет проверять на целостность программы?** Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Кучу раз это поднималось, могли бы и поискать. Хотите надежность, значит ваша программа должна быть простым клиентом, без какой либо "опасной логики". Пользователь запускает программу, та соединяется с сервером и уже сервер делает нужную работу, отправляя обратно данные. Если вы отдаете пользователю программу, которая всю эту логику делает у себя, то поверьте, рано или поздно, какая бы там не была защита, ее взломают, а вот ваш сервер - это уже под вопросом.

Comment: Технология WCF не предназначена для защиты приложения, это транспортный слой для обмена информацией с другими серверами, причём технология проприетарная, работающая только под windows с .net framework, под core её не портировали и в планах нет. Современный ближайший аналог - ну скажем webapi. Можете не смотреть в эту сторону, хотите надёжной защиты - выносите логику на серверную часть.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, здравствуйте еще раз! Спасибо за информативный ответ! Я только одно не могу понять, что значит : 'Выносить логику на сервер'? Т.е например вывести сгенерированный текст в TextBox. Человек нажимает на кнопку, она делает запрос серверу, а уже на сервере генерирует рандомный текст и возвращает в клиент -> TextBox?

Comment: @AK спасибо за информацию! Очень долго думал использовать или не использовать, до конца не понял что это и начал изучать. Спасибо за ответ! А то бы сейчас сидел и изучал то что не нужно! Можете подсказать? Как выглядит сервер, или куда мне копать что бы изучить это? Я не понимаю как это должно выглядеть когда на каком то сервере происходит логика моей программы.

Comment: Под сервером в данном случае понимается "сервер приложений", чаще всего - веб-сервер, который несёт сайт webapi который имеет доступ к базе данных и возвращает данные в формате json для вашего клиентского приложения. К коду сервеной части у клиента нет доступа - вот так и строится защита приложения, трейдофф достигается тем, что вам нужно следить за серверами, балансировать нагрузку, это деньги, вынужденные простои и требование чтобы у клиента был доступ в сеть интернет. И это не всем приложениям подходит.

Comment: @AK очень сложно. Мне нужно иметь сервер приложений? А сервер приложений как я понял не отличается от веб сервера, это как бы и есть собственно сервер приложений. Я как понял моя программа будет обращаться к веб-серверу и возвращать данные в формате json? И как я тоже понял, писать логику кода нельзя например на c#, c++ и так далее. Или я вот реально не чего не пойму. Какие то webapi... Много очень нового для меня.

Еще что я понял, если программа взаимодействует с  рабочем столом то сервер не сможет взаимодействовать с конкретным рабочим столом.

Comment: @AK и например для большого количество обработки данных, или какие то сложные вычисления, то сервер будет долго их слишком обрабатывать, если особенно их будет много. 

Я вот делал такую штуку WFC, там я создал класс, и сделал его как бы хостом, запустил и создал тестовую программу. Там программа обращается через прокси или через хост, даже не знаю еще как, но обращается к этому классу с данными а тот в свою очередь суммирует полученные данные и возвращает ответ моей программе.

Comment: @Komend Вариантов решить вашу задачу куча, все они сводятся к одному: Нужен механизм общения с сервером, который узнает клиента (по ключу, логику, да чему угодно), а затем будет отвечать на все его запросы. Уже готовых механизмов полным полно: сокеты, RPC, GraphQL, RestAPI и куча других. Сайт - это отлично описание приложения с интерфейсом, где логика идет на сервере. Вот представьте, что у вас есть чат, как реализуете? У каждого клиента будет общая логика, чтоб все знали как устроено ваше приложение, или логика будет у сервера, а клиенты лишь ее вызывать?

Comment: @Komend Если это простой пет проект, то как бы можно всем напихать одну логику, да и пусть все будут серверами, че уж там. А как быть если нужна авторизация? Все зашифрованные пароли и личные данные будете хранить у каждого клиента? Наверно нет. Значит нужен сервер, который будет иметь базу и отвечать на запросы. Ну так берете, пишете сервер, в нем авторизовываете клиента и принимаете от него данные, к примеру в JSON формате, аля `{"msg":"Привет мир!"}`, сервер получает это, выполняет свою логику и отдает ответ `{"result":"Привет!"}`, клиент читает и выводит на экран.

Comment: @Komend Думаю уже поняли, можете сделать хоть банальный калькулятор, хоть нейро. сеть, суть от этого не меняется. Нужен сервер, которые получает запросы, обрабатывает, запускает у себя логику, формирует и отдает ответ. Так что теперь думайте, что конкретно для вашего проекта лучше. Как по мне, самое простое и надежное, это использовать API, которое можно отлично расширить тем же GraphQL. Будет у вас висеть сайтик и обрабатывать запросы. Вон кстати можете систему комментариев на SO поглядеть, ведь идут запросы на сервер, где есть своя база, своя логика, о которой нам неведомо чего-либо.

Comment: @aepot, да, но я только узнал новый способ авторизации, мне нужно как-то эти данные прятать, весь код прятать. Спасибо вам за ответ!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо за подробное объяснение. Но все равно не ясно на 100%.
Понял что нужно писать сервер. Понял что нужно что-бы этот сервер принимал запросы. Только вот не понимаю как это все выглядеть будет.

Я попробовал написать программу с использованием .Net, этот сервер ждет его вызова клиента и возвращает ответ. Так примерно должно все выглядеть?

Comment: @Komend Как я вам уже сказал ранее, если не знаете что и как, берите готовое, используйте ASP NET.Core WebApi и на его основе стройте свой проект.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо за ответ! А все таки можно с помощи WCF все сделать? Я просто уже сервер написал и запросы к нему/ответы. Видел что так много кто кому советует если особенно прятать базу данных. Или это вообще не то? Так как во втором ответе сказали что не нужно использовать WCF. Или все таки NET.Core WebApi? Возможно они вообще отличаются

Comment: @Komend Технология WCF является устаревшей, заброшенной. Если вас это устраивает, дерзай, это один из способов общения сервер <-> клиент.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо! Теперь мне спокойнее. Попробую тогда NET.Core WebApi еще.